# How to start activity in portrait

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am working on `Activity1` given **landscape** in the manifest.

Now, I want to launch web browser in **portrait** from `Activity1` and keep it in `Activity1` landscape.

If it is possible, how can I do that?

This is my code:

**Activity1.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);        
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I want to launch web browser in portrait from Activity1 and keep it in Activity1 landscape? Means you want to put web browser inside activity view? or after launching web browser you want to make Activity1 landscape?

Comment: It means after launching web browser I want to **keep** Activity1 landscape.

Comment: Its easy. After your code just call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); it will force your activity in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't determinate orientation for not-yours-activity (app) with intent. if it supports landscape then it opens in landscape. Maybe its better to use own `WebView` in separated `Activity` with forced portrait orientation?

Comment: I see. I will try to use own WebView in separated Activity with forced portrait orientation!! Thank you very much for your suggestion.+*